# Funcion php para detectar comandos en un texto

Tags: php

Necesito poner texto en **negrita** de una variable **string** extraída de la **base de datos** pero no tengo idea de como se podría hacer, el ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr es el siguiente.

Mi idea seria poner un comando `*` al iniciar de el conjunto de palabras que quiero en negrita y al finalizar `*` de esta manera la función adecuada para hacer esto seria capaz de detectar que el texto que esta dentro de los signos de estrellas va en negrita.

Justamente como lo hace **stackoverflow** ,ahora bien el problema es que  necesitaría poner el texto en negrita que esta dentro de los signos de estrellas y a la vez quitar esos signos de estrella una vez detectados.

```
//esta seria la variable texto por ejemplo
```

> `$texto`=" **Un programador** es aquella persona que escribe, depura y
>   mantiene el código fuente de un programa informático, es decir, el
>   conjunto de instrucciones que **ejecuta el hardware** de una computadora,
>   para realizar una tarea determinada. ... **La programación** es una de las
>   principales disciplinas **dentro de la informática.**";

Como verán en la variable texto esos conjuntos de palabras están encerrados en signos de estrellas de **estackoverflow**, alguien por favor me podría ayudar o darme una pequeña idea de como se podría hacer esto? se los agradecería.

Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para reemplazar los asteriscos por etiquetas  podes utilizar un reemplazo mediante una expresión regular.

```
$text = '*Un programador* es aquella persona que escribe, depura y mantiene el código fuente de un programa informático, es decir, el conjunto de instrucciones que *ejecuta el hardware* de una computadora, para realizar una tarea determinada. ... La programación es una de las principales disciplinas *dentro de la informática*.';
$pattern = '/(\*(.*?)\*)/i';
$replace = '<strong>${2}</strong>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Lo que te va a dar la siguiente salida

```
<strong>Un programador</strong> es aquella persona que escribe, depura y mantiene el código fuente de un programa informático, es decir, el conjunto de instrucciones que <strong>ejecuta el hardware</strong> de una computadora, para realizar una tarea determinada. ... La programación es una de las principales disciplinas <strong>dentro de la informática</strong>.
```

Acá podes probarlo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a177bb1480841bd3404f8d572f965d3430afc616

Por último te recomiendo que si vas a permitir que los usuarios introduzcan estos textos uses algún sanitizador para evitar ataques XSS

Saludos

Comment: La verdad es interesante, se puede saber como se agregaría la cursiva? gracias!

Comment: Podes usar la etiqueta <em></em>. Te dejo un ejemplo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62d485565292e020a4c1578b8d9d3f86adb1f590

Comment: No sabia sobre `em`, Muchas gracias!

Comment: muy genial amigo! muchas gracias